# How do I reference a non-static member of a different class c#

Tags: c#, object, reference

I am trying to make a game where my background scrolls depending on how fast I want the player to be going.

I have tried creating a non-static function, that accesses BackgroundScroller.speed as a simple way to pass the value.

.

(PlayerController.cs)

```
void Setspeed(float setSpeed){

BackgroundScroller.speed = setSpeed;

}
```

BackgroundScroller.cs looks like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BackgroundScroller : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed = 0;
public static BackgroundScroller current;

float pos = 0;

void Start () {
    current = this;
}

public void Go () {
    pos += speed;
    if (pos > 1.0f)
        pos-= 1.0f;


    renderer.material.mainTextureOffset = new Vector2 (pos, 0);
}

}
```

.

The error I get when I try and access BackgroundScroller.speed from PlayerController.cs is: "An object reference is required to access non-static member "BackgroundScroller.speed".

I don't understand how to access the value of BackgroundScroller.speed from PlayerController.cs essentially. I don't want to create an object reference, I just want to simply change the value in the other class.

Cheers

Lucio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot statically access `speed` because it is not a static member. It is an instance variable that can only be accessed through an instantiated BackgroundScroller.

Assuming that `Start` has already been called somewhere ensuring that `BackgroundScroller.current` is not null, the following line will give you access to the speed to use the existing static reference for the current scroller.

```
BackgroundScroller.current.speed = setSpeed;
```

Comment: Works perfectly cheers. I'm an idiot too, the .current is used earlier on in the tutorial I followed, which calls go(). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `speed` is not static type and you can fix this by adding static in `speed` variable.

Try to change your speed type to `static float`, for example

```
public static float speed;
```

then you can finally set the value of `speed`

```
void Setspeed(float setSpeed){
    BackgroundScroller.speed = setSpeed;
}
```